# What is the reason why at low temperatures the electromagnetic interaction becomes short ranged?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

We know that at very low temperatures, the electrons start forming Cooper pairs and generate some sort of eddy current, so that a magnetic flux that is trying to penetrate the low-temperature object will be "canceled" after some distance.

But what is the physical mechanism behind this? As the temperature is getting lower, the atoms are vibrating slower and slower. What effect does that have on the electrons inside the crystal?